# Visual Studio tells me a css class is not defined when clearly it is

Tags: css, visual-studio-2008, stylesheet

I'm using Visual Studio 2008 making an ASP.NET page. In this page I'm using a stylesheet at styles/basic.css

When I hit F5 to load the page it loads perfectly fine. Inside the style sheet I have defined a .basic style class along with other classes. But when I use body class="basic", Visual Studio tells me "The class or CssClass value is not defined."

I've tried to name it body.basic, I've tried renaming basic to a variety of other names, with and without body, but visual studio continues to lie to me and I can't figure out why!

Anyone else come across this/know how to fix it? I noticed one thing - I can use another class name I have: div.opaque, and VS doesn't tell me it's undefined even though it's clearly not a body class? Also I tried renaming it div.basic but that didn't work either.

Comment: I know this isn't helpful to your problem, but I think most people generally ignore Visual Studio's CSS warnings.  Not only for the problem you are seeing, but also because CSS classes may be used purely for selecting elements via Javascript, meaning that a CSS rule will not exist for them on purpose.

Comment: Yeah, it's not terribly important... but what can I say? I'm one of those perfectionist-type geeks and not understanding WHY it does what it does is REALLY annoying to me >_<

Comment: I think it might use useful to see an HTML and CSS segment from your actual code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, my current workaround is to just remove the class parameter from the body and just declare body{} in the CSS. Pesky, but works.